# C++ Getline simple error

Tags: c++, getline

I would like to point I am not good in C++, I usually use C but i thought that get to know some C++ basic will be good so I need to send data to server and normal std::cin >> variable can't do it because it only reads input to space so I read about getline and it's working great, but when I do something liek this in infinite loop:

```
for (;;)
{
std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;;
std::getline(std::cin,darek.wiadomosc);
}
```

Durning first itteration it shows on screen double Hello like:
Hello 
Hello
String that is being entered

But after one loop it shows everything good. It's problem with getline I'm sure because when I changed it to std::cin >> just for test it worked. Can anybody answer to my simple question?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You shouldn't be surprised there's an infinite loop: you used `for(;;)` and have no breaks from it. In any case, you might want to check out an [introductory C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) so you can learn the language properly; your C knowledge will only prove useful for a small subset of C++ *syntax*, and probably not useful at all for idiomatic and correct C++ coding.

Comment: I know that thre is no break... I just wanted to use it for test I know how to handle break from loop, it's not the topic.

Comment: What compiler and OS are you using? This works fine (printing only one Hello at the beginning) for me on Windows and Visual C++. The problem is probably that your OS/running environment doesn't clear standard input when running the program thus making the first getline return immediately. Without more info I can't say that for sure though.

Comment: OS Win XP SP2 Compiler: Visual C++ 2008 EE

Comment: @Darek: Sorry, I guess I'm just confused with what you were expecting and what you got. Can you state what your high-level goal is?

Comment: It's just beggining of multi-thread server and I can send one message to server and get respond to client but I added this infinite loop so I could write more than just one line before program exits. It's probably related to clearing input like dark_charlie mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

`std::cin` leaves the terminator in the stream (be it a space or a newline). 
So if you do:

```
std::string foo, bar;
std::cin >> foo;
std::getline(std::cin, bar);
```

with input as:

```
Hello
World
```

`bar` will end up with the empty string, not "World", because `getline` will stop at the first newline, which is the one after "Hello".

To bring this back to your question, if you have instances of `std::cin >>` before the start of your loop, you may have a stray newline, making the first iteration behave in unexpected ways. You can use `std::cin.ignore` to ignore any newlines left in the stream.

Comment: Yes I have one std::cin before loop. I will check it out. Worked, props and thanks : D